# How does this ending particle じ work?

Tags: particles

I've seen this particle used before multiple times but have chosen to ignore it each time. Though here's an example where I can find this particle being used.

冬来りなば春遠からじ - (from what I guess it might mean, "When winter comes, spring can't be that far behind")

Comment: FWIW, the example sentence belongs to a poem, it is a translation from a the last line of [Ode to the West Wind](https://poets.org/poem/ode-west-wind) by [Percy Bysshe Shelley](https://poets.org/poet/percy-bysshe-shelley), and the original line in the poem says "If Winter comes, can Spring be far behind?", so we are possibly talking of literary-only, [classic](https://www.kotenbunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%98/) and/or obsolete material. See a reference in Japanese [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/冬来りなば春遠からじ/).

Answer (score 4):

It is an archaic auxiliary verb [じ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%98/#jn-92527).

It means *will not*. Thus 春遠からじ means *spring won't be far*.

---

In modern usage, it appears mostly in fixed expressions like 負けじと.